# Rich:extendedDataTable column go beyond bounds of layout at the load of page

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I have an `rich:extendedDatable` (see code bellow). When I am on a big screen, no problem, when I am changing the size of my windows manually, no problem, the column resize well. But if I am on a little screen/window on the load of the page, the columns go beyond the bounds of the layout (screen 1 bellow). If after that I resize a little my window, all go in order (screen 2 bellow).

I have try to put width 25% on my column and `style="table-layout:fixed;"` on extendedDatable but this doesn't work.

Code:

```
<rich:tabPanel>
    <rich:tab label="Abonnés">
        <a4j:outputPanel id="tabInfosGroupe">
            <rich:panel>
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText
                        value="Individus, groupes composant le groupe #{GroupeController.currentGroupe.llGroupe}" />
                </f:facet>

                <rich:layout>
                    <rich:layoutPanel position="left">
                        <h:outputText value="Groupes intitutionnels :" />
                            <a4j:commandLink ajaxSingle="true" id="editLinkComposante"
                                <h:graphicImage value="/img/create_doc.gif"
                                    style="border:0" />
                            </a4j:commandLink>
                        <rich:separator />
                        <rich:extendedDataTable style="table-layout:fixed;" groupingColumn="colLibStructure"
                            sortMode="single" id="tableComposantes"
                            rendered="#{not empty GroupeController.listTupleRepartGroupePersonne}"
                            value="#{GroupeController.listTupleRepartGroupePersonne}"
                            var="tuple" >
                            <rich:column  id="colLibStructure" label="Service"
                                selfSorted="true"
                                sortBy="#{tuple.groupe.structureUlr.llStructure}">
                                <f:facet name="header">
                                    <h:outputText value="Service" />
                                </f:facet>
                                <h:outputText
                                    value="#{tuple.groupe.structureUlr.llStructure}" />
                                <h:outputText
                                    rendered="#{tuple.groupe.structureUlrLien eq 'strAndSub'}"
                                    value=" (et les sous services)" />
                                <h:outputText
                                    rendered="#{tuple.groupe.structureUlrLien eq 'str'}"
                                    value=" (service uniquement)" />
                                    <a4j:commandButton id="idSupprimerComposante"
                                        style="margin-left:50px;width:50%;" value="Supprimer" />
                            </rich:column>

                            <rich:column  label="prenom" id="colPrenom"
                                selfSorted="true"
                                sortBy="#{tuple.personne.individuUlrs[0].prenomAffichage}">
                                <f:facet name="header">
                                    <h:outputText value="Prenom" />
                                </f:facet>
                                <a4j:outputPanel rendered="#{tuple.isExclude()}">
                                    <del style="color: red">
                                        <h:outputText
                                            value="#{tuple.personne.individuUlrs[0].prenomAffichage}" />
                                    </del>
                                </a4j:outputPanel>
                                <a4j:outputPanel rendered="#{!tuple.isExclude()}">
                                    <h:outputText
                                        value="#{tuple.personne.individuUlrs[0].prenomAffichage}" />
                                </a4j:outputPanel>
                            </rich:column>

                            <rich:column  label="nom" selfSorted="true"
                                sortBy="#{tuple.personne.individuUlrs[0].nomAffichage}">
                                <f:facet name="header">
                                    <h:outputText value="Nom" />
                                </f:facet>
                                <a4j:outputPanel rendered="#{tuple.isExclude()}">
                                    <del style="color: red">
                                        <h:outputText
                                            value="#{tuple.personne.individuUlrs[0].nomAffichage}" />
                                    </del>
                                </a4j:outputPanel>
                                <a4j:outputPanel rendered="#{!tuple.isExclude()}">
                                    <h:outputText
                                        value="#{tuple.personne.individuUlrs[0].nomAffichage}" />
                                </a4j:outputPanel>
                            </rich:column>

                            <rich:column  label="Exclure" >
                                <f:facet name="header">
                                    <h:outputText value="Exclure" />
                                </f:facet>
                                <a4j:outputPanel rendered="#{!tuple.isExclude()}">
                                    <a4j:commandButton id="idExclure" value="Exclure" style="width:100%;" />
                                </a4j:outputPanel>
                                <a4j:outputPanel rendered="#{tuple.isExclude()}">
                                    <a4j:commandButton id="idAnnExclure" style="width:100%;"value="Annuler l'exclusion"/>
                                </a4j:outputPanel>
                            </rich:column>
                        </rich:extendedDataTable>
                    </rich:layoutPanel>
```

[screen 1, on load](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sqz6J.png)
[screen 2, after resize](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K8mnS.png)

Comment: AFAIK width in % aren't supported in extandedDataTables. This was (still is?) the main reason why i don't use them (i use simple dataTable).

Comment: Also, and this is really important, it looks like you're using RF 3.3.X (you should mention that), which is about 7 years old and isn't supported from about 2012 ;-)

Comment: Ok, thank :)
I will try with dataTables so
I have not choose the version, I am an intern, If it was me I have switch all to primefaces or thing like that ^^. So sorry, I don't know the version of all component :/

Comment: I finally solve it by put width="20%" on 3 of my columns and left the last without width parameter